# Mongoose FindOne not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm getting a null response from Mongoose FindOne if i put as parameter a dateString argument. I'm using nodejs and mongoose.

Here is my code:

```
var Service = app.models.service;
controller.newService = function(req, res) {
var date = new Date();
var dateString = date.toString();
var countHours = 1;
var user = req.decoded;
var findProfessional = function(){
    console.log(countHours);
    console.log(user._doc._id);
    console.log(req.body.service[0].tipo);
    console.log(dateString);
    Service.findOne({
      tipo: req.body.service[0].tipo,
      client: user._doc._id,
      dateOpen: dateString
    }, function(err, service) {
      console.log(service);
      if (err) throw err;

      if (!service) {
        console.log("service not found");
      } else if (service) {
        if (service.status == 'open' && countHours <= 24) {
          setTimeout(function(){
            Professional.find({
              'services.name': req.body.service[0].tipo
            }, function(err, professional) {
              if (err) throw err;

              if (professional) {
                DO STUFF                      
              } else {
                DO STUFF
                res.json({ success: false, message: 'No professionals found' });
              };
            });
            countHours++;
            findProfessional();
          }, 10000);
        } else if (service.status != 'open'){
          // DO STUFF
        } else if (countHours > 24){
          //DO STUFF
        }
      }
    });
  };
```

Here is my schema:

```
var schemaServices = mongoose.Schema({
    tipo: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    client: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    dateOpen: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    dateClose: {
        type: String,
    },
    professional: {
        type: String
    },
    status: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    services: {
        type: [{name: String,
            preco: String,
            tipo: String,
            tipoCusto: String,
            pedido: String}],
        required: true
        },
    visitDay: {
        type: String
    },
    visitHour: {
        type: String
    },
    address: {
        type: [{cep: String,
            street: String,
            number: String,
            comp: String,
            district: String,
            city: String}],
        required: true
    }
    });

schemaServices.index({client: 1, tipo: 1, dateOpen: 1}, {unique: true});
```

**What my code do?**

When a request is made to this route, node saves the new service and looks for a professional to do the job. And it keep looking for until the timer countHours reachs 24 or haves a professional to do the work. Server is saving the service without problems, but i need to check the status of the Service that was just saved, and i'm facing this problem of Service.findOne() returning null values when i put dateOpen: dateString.

**The Problem is**

```
 Service.findOne({
      tipo: req.body.service[0].tipo,
      client: user._doc._id,
      dateOpen: dateString
    }
```

Is always returning a null value like service doesn't exists. But if i made the same query in prompt using mongo, i got the right service.

**I made some tests and observed some things:**

*- The console.logs are printing alright what it should print.

-When i remove the dateOpen: dateString from arguments in Service.findOne() it works*

So, i believe that the error is related with the dateString, but i can't see what it is.

Hope someone can help me,

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You are saving the date as string. Check that they are in same format. Otherwise, it will not return the desired result. 

I recommend to save the date as Date type. Then you could use the Date() object directly in query to find the result.

Comment: Yep look at your documents, and the results of your console.log(dateString) .  Feel free to post an example in your question.

Comment: Thank you guys, just solved. The formats was the same.

Answer (score 0):

Just solved my own problem.

The problem was that the execution time of node was faster than the .save method of mongo, just changed the call of findProfessional() into the success callback of .save method. Like that:

```
     newService.save(function(err){
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Service saved successfully');
    newService.save(findProfessional())
  });
```

Now, its working properly.